# SASS putting double property name, why?

Tags: css, sass

Messing around in SASS but when my stylesheet is compiling it generates this weird, invalid css.

```
.container     
        padding: 3rem 2.5rem 3rem
        background-color: red
```

[image]

Since this compiles well in isolation it must be the surrounding sass as pointed out in the comments. If it matters anything it's an angular 5 project:

Surrounding sass: https://pastebin.com/tMMxf97D

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you don't have to use `;` or `{ }` somewhere ?

Comment: Don't need to, it's `sass` not `scss`. It compiled well to me. Can you show the surrounding `sass` code?

Comment: @muecas https://pastebin.com/tMMxf97D

Comment: check it out https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/4c35cf824d885ac58a401352c34d0bda

Comment: Compiler mismatch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some extra spaces, and inconsistent tabs. I added the variables just to test. [Check my rearranged code](https://pastebin.com/z9HDKTyy)

```
$prim: #cccccc
$dark-prim: #666666
$grey: grey

#wrapper
  background: #F7F7F7

  .tournament-card 
    background: #fff
    box-shadow: 0 0 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11)

    .card-title 
      background-color: $dark-prim
      padding: 2rem

      h1
        color: #fff
        text-align: center
        font-size: 1.2rem

    .container
      padding: 3rem 2.5rem 3rem
      background-color: red

    .options
      color: $grey
      margin-bottom: 1.5rem

    button
      cursor: pointer
      font-size: 1.2rem
      color: $prim
      border-radius: 4rem
      display: block
      width: 100%
      background: transparent
      border: 2px solid $prim
      padding: 0.9rem 0 1.1rem
      transition: color .5s, border-color .5s
      margin-top: 3rem

      &:hover,
      &:focus
        background: $dark-prim
        color: white

      &:active
        transform: translateY(1px)
```

Comment: Thank you that did the trick! I didn't know sass is so sensitive regarding spaces/tabs.

Comment: Yes, that's why i prefer `scss` over `sass` :) Mark as solved if it did the trick. Thanks!